# Autocomplete inside modal working bad with selections on Ipad

Tags: python, django, ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-autocomplete-light

Using:

- Django-autocomplete-light https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light
- Bootstrap3 modal http://getbootstrap.com/

When having a form with an autocomplete inside a modal, the selection of items on Ipad (iOS7) will be very buggy. Selection of item will work 1/3 of the times

Form outside modal works as expected.

My guess is some css rules messing it up. But I haven't been able to track it down myself

Answer (score 1):

**Found the solution.**

Changing the Modals position to 'absolute' instead of 'fixed' solved the problem (Damn iOS safari caching old stylesheets)

I didn't however want to put the css on all browsers so I did it with:

`if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null){
        $('#modal').css('position','absolute')
}`